# python how does this function get to line 10

Tags: python, python-3.6

I would expect myfunction to return 0 and not execute the finally but why does it do so?

```
def myfunction(i):
    try:
        result=10/i
    except:
        return 0
    finally:
        return 10 

print(myfunction(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

the code in the finally section will run no matter what happens in the catch block ( except for the times that your program terminates somehow before reaching  the finally section) if you want for it not to run you should alter your code like this:

```
def myfunction(i):
    try:
        result=10/i
    except:
        return 0
    return 10
```

Answer (score 0):

[`finally`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) is always executed, regardless exception occurred or not. The documentation is very clear in that essence:

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception has occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except clause (or it has occurred in an except or else clause), it is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.

So the `return` statement in the `finally` clause overrides the one from the `exception` clause. It doesn't make much sense to put `return` statement inside a `finally` clause, as this would be the only value returned from a function.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `10` because the `finally` clause in your `try` block executes before any `return` statement as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805654/python-try-finally-block-returns).

It's also worth noting that you're using the generic `except` which will result in a lot of unintended behaviour. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python) for how to best construct `try/except` blocks and best `raise` exceptions.