# python exception not raised if finally returns value

Tags: python, exception, try-except

Can anyone explain why the following example does not raise the `Exception`?

```
def foo():
    try:
        0/0
    except Exception:
        print('in except')
        raise
    finally:
        print('in finally')
        return 'bar'

my_var = foo()
print(my_var)
```

This just returns:

```
in except
in finally
bar
```

Where as the same code without the `return 'bar'` statement throws the exception:

```
in except
in finally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    my_var = foo()
  File "test.py", line 3, in foo
    0/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: you can catch the exception, assign it to a previously defined None variable and then reraise it in finally:  Bit trickier to get working in python 3 than 2, i’ll post it later.  useful to close resources but still throw the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19805813/1358308 for more detail, but in brief

the `finally` block should always be executed, Python therefore has to ignore the `raise` statement as that would violate semantics