# what is the difference between returning from finally block in try-except-finally and outside of finally?

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

Could someone please explain the difference between -

```
def f():
    try:
        print('A', end=' ')
        raise ArithmeticError
    except:
        print('B', end=' ')
        raise AssertionError
    finally:
        print('C', end=' ')
        return
```

And

```
def f():
    try:
        print('A', end=' ')
        raise ArithmeticError
    except:
        print('B', end=' ')
        raise AssertionError
    finally:
        print('C', end=' ')
    return
```

The first code block does not raise any exceptions and print "A B C" while the second code block raises both exceptions and prints "A B C".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python try finally block returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805654/python-try-finally-block-returns)

Comment: @AppleBS - Well, I understand how finally works but I still don't get why I don't see any exceptions in the first case

Answer (score 0):

Because `finally` is guaranteed to be executed whether exception is raised or not.

Therefore, when you `return` in the finally block, you simply returned void and not the exception (or any other previously returned value).

Take this for example:

```
def f3():
    try:
        return "Try"
    finally:
        return "Finally"
```

When you print `f3()`, you will get `Finally`.