# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'audio_segment' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I have a function that used ElevenLabs API which worked fine. However, it incurred a lot of cost even during prototyping. So I thought it would be best to go for Edge-TTS. I am getting an error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'audio_segment' where it is not associated with a value
```

Here's the ElevenLabs API code:

```
from elevenlabs import generate, set_api_key, Voice, VoiceSettings
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import os
import hashlib
from utils.os_stuff import get_env_var_or_fail
import logging

set_api_key(get_env_var_or_fail('ELEVEN_LABS_API_KEY'))

HOST_VOICE = Voice(
    voice_id="21m00Tcm4TlvDq8ikWAM",
    name="Rachel",
    category="premade",
    settings=VoiceSettings(stability=0.35, similarity_boost=0.9),
)

ADS_VOICE = Voice(
    voice_id="TxGEqnHWrfWFTfGW9XjX",
    name="Josh",
    category="premade",
    settings=VoiceSettings(stability=0.35, similarity_boost=0.9),
)


def load_audio_bytes(audio_bytes):
    audio_file = io.BytesIO(audio_bytes)
    audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file, format='mp3')
    return audio_segment


def convert_text_to_mp3(text, voice):
    # Generate the cache key by MD5 hashing the text
    cache_key = hashlib.md5(text.encode()).hexdigest()

    # Check if the file already exists in cache
    cache_dir = ".eleven_labs_cache"
    cache_file = os.path.join(cache_dir, f"{cache_key}.mp3")

    if not os.path.exists(cache_dir):
        os.makedirs(cache_dir)

    if os.path.exists(cache_file):
        # If it does exist, load and return as an AudioSegment
        audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_mp3(cache_file)
    else:
        # If it does not exist, call the API, create, save, and return as an AudioSegment
        char_count = len(text)
        logging.info(f'Calling eleven labs for {char_count} chars...')
        section_1_voice_over = load_audio_bytes(generate(
            text=text,
            voice=voice
        ))
        section_1_voice_over.export(cache_file, format='mp3')
        audio_segment = section_1_voice_over

    return audio_segment
```

And here's the Edge-TTS code:

```
import asyncio
import edge_tts
from pydub import AudioSegment

VOICE = "en-GB-SoniaNeural"

def convert_text_to_mp3(text):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
    try:
        audio_segment = loop.run_until_complete(edge_tts.Communicate(text, VOICE))
    finally:
        loop.close()
        return audio_segment
```

I tried to rewrite the function without async but that didn't work either. Can somebody please help me understand where am I going wrong or how to rectify this code.

Comment: Add your complete traceback so we know which line produced the error

Comment: In the second code sample, if the `try` block encounters an exception, the `audio_segment = ...` assignment never happens, and so the `audio_segment` variable does not exist to be returned in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mark Tolonen mentioned, it's hard to debug without your full stack trace. However, looking at your `convert_text_to_mp3` function, your return of `audio_segment` is not safe, because that value will not be set in the case that the call to `loop.run_until_complete(edge_tts.Communicate...` fails. If your code raises an exception within that function call, then that is likely the cause of the error that you have described.

I would recommend initializing `audio_segment` to a default value, such as `None`, before your try clause, so in the case of a raised exception, the variable will not be unbound. Something like this:

```py
def convert_text_to_mp3(text):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
    audio_segment = None

    try:
        audio_segment = loop.run_until_complete(edge_tts.Communicate(text, VOICE))
    finally:
        loop.close()
    
    return audio_segment
```

**Sidenote:** Having a `return` in your `finally` clause can cause unintended behavior due to the order of execution, so to avoid possible headaches down the road, I would also recommend moving that below and outside of the clause. More info on how the order of execution flows can be found here: [Python try finally block returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805654/python-try-finally-block-returns)

**Response to the comment:** You can use a wrapper function like so:

```py
async def wrapper():
    edge_tts.Communicate(text, VOICE)

def convert_text_to_mp3():
...
        loop.run_until_complete(wrapper)
...
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply everyone. @awarrier99, I tried the sample code you provided and got an error "TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required", here's the traceback: https://pastebin.com/FZQZpnJR

Comment: @RajtilakBhattacharjee this is an unrelated error to your original question which probably should be posted in its own separate question. However, if I had to guess, it's likely because you are invoking the `edge_tts.Communicate` within your function call; if it doesn't return another coroutine, then this is an invalid usage as you are passing the return value of the function to be invoked. You can avoid this by using a wrapper function, which I will include in a note at the bottom of my post

Comment: This was the initial traceback: https://pastebin.com/jhYmWyKs. After which, I started tinkering with the code and changed it to this: https://pastebin.com/6yuYvByK. On changing the code, I got another error. Here's the traceback for the same: https://pastebin.com/8kHRkCAY

Comment: @RajtilakBhattacharjee the latest errors you have shown are now completely unrelated to the issue you posted about, and seems to deal more with the internals of the libraries that you are using (which I am not at all familiar with). Please post these separate issues that you're having in another question so that someone with more familiarity with the topic can help you out and so that this post can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
import asyncio
import edge_tts

VOICE = "en-GB-SoniaNeural"


async def converter(text, filename):
    audio_segment = edge_tts.Communicate(text, VOICE)
    await audio_segment.save("app/cache/" + filename)


def convert_text_to_mp3(text, filename):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
    audio_segment = loop.run_until_complete(converter(text, filename))
    return audio_segment
```

Thanks everyone for your time and patience. We are able to successfully migrate from OpenAI and ElevenLabs to llmOS and edge-tts.